# Nemo - remove items from context menu

Tags: uninstall, nemo, context-menu

I would like to ask you how can I remove some items from context menu in Nemo File Manager.

I mean this items:

- Set as Wallpaper
- Send with Thunderbird

There is image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those items - in Nemo called actions - can reside in the follwing directories:

- `/usr/share/nemo/actions/`
- `/usr/local/share/nemo/actions/`
- `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/`

Those files have a structure similar to desktop launchers; [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action) is a well documented example.

From this example:

```
# Whether this action is active.  For troubleshooting.
# Optional - if this field is omitted, the action will be active
Active=false
```

So if you want to disable an action, open the corresponding file in a text editor (requires a rooted editor for the system-wide directories) and put

```
Active=false
```

at the end. Save the file and restart Nemo from a terminal:

```
killall nemo && nemo -n
```

**EDIT**: In newer versions of Nemo, there is a plugin manager, which can be opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This may be easier. As the version in Ubuntu's repos (1.8.4 at the time of writing) doesn't yet have this feature, you can install a later version e.g. from the webupd8 repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
killall nemo && nemo -n
```

If you want to use more features, such as various Nemo extensions, best read [this article on webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html).

Comment: In directories usr/ and home/ i dont have any actions, and please how can I update Nemo to newer version if Ubuntu Software Center doesn't give me a chance to update, it is version 1.8.4-1.1

Comment: I updated my answer with installation instructions.