# Remove "Organize Desktop by Name" option

Tags: nemo

I have nemo as my default file browser in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Is there a way to remove the "Organize Desktop by Name" option which appears when you right click on the Desktop? I keep accidentally clicking it when I mean to open something else and would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/721184/nemo-remove-items-from-context-menu